Consciousness and language?
I would like to read upon the finer points of defining consciousness. One view is that consciousness whatever it is cannot be commited to language - (a possible wittgenstien viewpoint).The other view is everything is consciousness - panscyism. Note they are not necessarily in contradiction.
Where can I read of a good exchange between philosophers of both these viewpoints?

Sigmund Freud describes the ego as the conscious part of the biological organism. The biological function of the ego is to regulate or control efforts to govern action in the sensory context. Although Freud did not state this insight, if one contemplates the effort to govern action in the sensory context, it is a generic mode of self-other communication. Nature does not have the attributes of human-other, and we associate communication with interactions with human-other(s). But in drama the themes of man versus nature or man versus God (see Book of Job) also have attributes of communication.

These descriptions are too vague to be useful. Can you expand on them?

Wittgenstien has a different tradition from Socratic dialogue when it comes to asking what is the essence of stuff. The language game of defining consciousness may be meaningless and the correct thing to do might be to remain silent as an answer. This is one side of the argument.

I think Penrose had the idea that everything is conscious, perhaps he debated with other philosophers about it?

I am not aware of works relating language to panpsychism. Some approaches to describing aspects of consciousness include language of thought and higher-order representations. Panpsychist description of consciousness revolves around solving the combination problem, and PhilPapaers has a nice survey of literature on it.
